# Get printed copy of specific journal

Tags: journals

A simple question:

Is there a way to get a specific issue of a journal as a printed copy?

I do not want a subscription, I just want printed copies of a very limited number of issues, mainly from "Econometrica", "Games and Economic Behaviour" and "American Economic Review".

Comment: Did you contact the editorial management of these journals?

Comment: Not yet, but surely will do.

Comment: Yep, cause that is the way to do it if you want an "official" copy: you order it directly from the publisher.  If they don't have it, probably nobody does (you could try eBay etc but it is unlikely).  Caution though, you may have to pick your jaw up off the floor when you see the price they quote you.  Otherwise, you find a library that has a subscription, and either photocopy their print copy, or download and print the PDFs.

Comment: If you're enrolled at a college/university, they should have the ability to request a copy for you.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the website of the American Economic Review and indeed they do not offer online purchase of single issues. What I would do in such an instance is contact the journal directly, preferably by calling them over the phone. Email inquiries about isolated requests of single issues notoriously tend to end up on the bottom of the endless pile. A simple phone call will likely provide you with the information you are after.

Also, I've obtained copies of dated issues on eBay and Amazon. Often a university's library empties its stock once in a while and their items appear on the market. This concerns older issues of course.

As a last, but worthy shot - Simply type in the specifics of the journal issue on Google and see what happens. Play around a little bit with notations (full journal title, abbreviated title, include the publisher, or not, *etcetera*).

Answer (score 0):

A diminishing number universities still have these journals on the shelves. Most of the time you can just walk in and take them off and use them in the library. If you have access to them you can just photocopy the whole thing and print it yourself.

I presume you don't have institution access to them, otherwise why not just download them and print them?

Comment: Well the idea is to have some of my favourite articles in my bookshelf - and not copied or self printed, but in their old fashioned form of a printed Journal.

Comment: @ottlngr unless your research budget is near infinity, then I'm guessing you will abandon this except for maybe 5 articles or so.